# program to view addresses of elements in an array

Tags: c++

help plz its showing invalid indirection
i used it to find the location or memory addresses of elements in the array b

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
clrscr();
int *ptr;
int b[]={1,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
ptr=b;
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
cout<<ptr[i]<<" "<<*b[i];
}
```

Comment: Use pointer arithmetic (remember that `b[i]` is equivalent to `*(b + i)`) or the address-of operator?

Comment: `I used it to know the addresses of values in b ` This is not a question.

Comment: Are you going to ask a question? This is a Q&A site, not a repository for anecdotes.

Comment: Going "help plzzzz" is so not professional.

Comment: sorry new to stack overflow

Comment: Also note that `*b[i]` is the same as `*(b[i])`, that is you treat `b[i]` as a pointer and dereference it, and since it's not a pointer you have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should probably get warnings about that, always listen to what the compiler tells you!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It's not undefined behavior. It's an ill-formed program.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print the address of the i<sup>th</sup> element in an array `b`, use

```
std::cout << b + i;
```

This will work in all cases except when `b` is an array of `char`, in which case you need to cast to `void*`

```
std::cout << static_cast<const void*>(b + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

in place of iostream.h it should be iostream.

void main() ; it should be int main().

```
cout<<ptr[i]<<" "<<(b+i)<<endl;
```

Formatting by using endl  in above line of code will make the result clear.

Your function should return an integer value.

```
return 0;
```